# Special characters are getting converted in php

Tags: php, oracle11g

I am using PHP 5.2.9 and Apache httpd with Oracle database. I am also using the ADOdb PHP library.

When I provide some special character data from a web form, say `John's home`, it is getting converted to `John&#039;s home` and it is going into the database like this as well.

What's wrong? Have I have misconfigured any settings?

Comment: are you using  `htmlentities()` by any chance ? if so, try using `html_entity_decode()` before the `insert`

Comment: will this help you?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Worth to mention: PHP5.2.x is ... old. Consider an update.

Comment: @KingCrunch, Oracle drivers in PHP 5.3 or later are a real hassle to get functioning on some platforms.  I'd suspect that's why 5.2 is still in use.